# java call parent's callback function in inner function

Tags: java, android, callback

platform: android

I'm new to java, I want to do something like this:

```
private void PostToServer(final Callback mycallback){

    OkHttpClient client= new OkHttpClient();
    //some codes....
    client.newCall(req).enqueue(new Callback(){
       private void onFailure(Request req,IOException e){
           tip("SERVER ERROR!");
       }
       private void onResponse(Response resp){
          Call mycallback(resp); //how to call the callback?
       }
    }
}
```

I want to use it like this:(make a interface my own?)

```
PostToServer(new callback(){
    @Override
    private void onSuccess(String resp){
      if(resp==1){
         tip("SERVER CONNECTED!");
      }
    }
});
```

**GOAL:** call mycallback in onResponse().

btw what is this type of code called? what are the keywords should I use to search?

thanks so much!

**okhttp callback interface:** [direct link](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Callback.java)

```
package com.squareup.okhttp;    
import java.io.IOException;

public interface Callback {    
  void onFailure(Request request, IOException e);    
  void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException;
}
```

Comment: which method is the "main function's callback"? clarify your question please. Do you want to call a method on the callback parameter given in the dothings method??

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the concrete question is. But you are using an anonymous inner class. And you can only access objects from the outside if they are final. With Java 8 your callback parameter should be implicit final. If you are using Java 7 (which you are doing in case of Android IIRC) you need to mark your parameter with the final keyword.

If you are asking about the design pattern you are trying to achieve ... what you are doing is similar to functional programming, as you are passing the function that should be executed as callback object.

Comment: my purpose is : call main function's callback from  callback's function's inner function.

Comment: In that case simply add the final keyword to your method parameter:

'private void dothings(final Callback callback) {'

Comment: I updated my codes, hope it's better to understand. Sorry.

Comment: your callback is an object, an object has methods, so simply call the specified method of your callback instance. Since you didn't show the Callback interface, I am not aware of that interface, and your sample only shows private methods (which are not specified in an interface as every method in an interface has to be public), I can't tell you which method to call.